# mail send using smtp.office365.com failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, smtp, office365

Hi I'm used to send mail from asp.net mvc,C# code but the problem is its not work from site which start with HTTP, not any problem for send mail from site start with HTTPS. I didn't get what's the problem for this issue. I'm used below code for send mails

```
var hostEmail = ConfigurationExtensions.GetAppConfigValue("SMTPUserName").ToString();
var hostPassword = ConfigurationExtensions.GetAppConfigValue("SMTPPassword").ToString();
var fromEmail = ConfigurationExtensions.GetAppConfigValue("EmailFrom").ToString();

SmtpClient ss = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = ConfigurationExtensions.GetAppConfigValue("EmailHost").ToString(),
    Port = ConfigurationExtensions.GetAppConfigValue<int>("smtpPort"),
    Timeout = 20000,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    EnableSsl = true,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(hostEmail, hostPassword)
};

MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage(hostEmail, email, subject, msg)
{
    From = new MailAddress(fromEmail, mailname),
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
};
ss.Send(mailMsg);
```

My config code send below

```
<add key="EmailHost" value="smtp.office365.com" />
<add key="EnableSsl" value="true" />
<add key="smtpPort" value="587" />
<add key="SMTPUserName" value="test@test.com" />
<add key="SMTPPassword" value="password" />
<add key="EmailFrom" value="test@test.com" />
<add key="EmailUser" value="Test User" />
<add key="EmailID" value="test@test.com" />
```

Error screenshots attached below
[inner exception error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3j43.png)
[message fail error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hTU1.png)

Also checked this issue in different sites but not get the solution.
Problem only exist while sites start in http:, not any issues in https:
Anybody know the solution ? please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See [POP, IMAP, and SMTP settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353) for possible settings. You need to use a secured connection with the right ports to be able to communicate with a server.

Comment: SMTP Settings are provide same like but showing issue
Error screenshot attached through qn